# Software for On-the-fly-mapping

Tags: tools, map-making

While mapping has been extensively covered but always from either the Virtual Tabletop perspective, not the on-the-fly-mapping idea. Basically what software could you use to map a grid-based dungeon in real time? It doesn't have to look pretty, the current tool in use is Excel with square cells & cell boarders. However the 'right tool for the right job' person in me pulls my hair out every time I hear this, so I want something better. It must be at least as fast as excel, support marking of secret & normal doors and such. I plan my dungeons on grid-paper, so rectangle only is fine for now.

This is just for old-school mapping: Not a battle mat, not for online play. Just something that is easier to share then scanning in a sheet of grid paper.

**No Mac or iOS solutions. Android, Windows and Linux are what we use** 
More obscure OS programs are also allowed, due to the fact we are huge nerds.

Comment: Have you looked at Maptools?

Comment: That stuff called 'paper' seems to work pretty well.

Comment: You have to pay for paper every time you use it, it can't be transferred across the internet without equipment, same for equipment, and Canageek asked for something other than paper explicitly.

Comment: @nitsua60 I asked it three years ago, so I'm not surprised if it isn't allowed anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like MapTool. I've also been known to use the GIMP to tile together images, but that's only worthwhile if you've already got tiles.

I've actually used the toolkit from the original Neverwinter Nights to generate a map, but this is rather slow and whatnot.

I've also messed around with other things but they're mostly random in nature, so I'm assuming you don't want them. If you are, I'd suggest http://donjon.bin.sh.

Also, I just found an awesome site for this: http://pyromancers.com/dungeon-painter-online/

Hopefully one of these is helpful.

Edit: [Dunjinni](http://www.dunjinni.com/) looks like it could potentially be cool, but I'm not very familiar with it. There's also [Dungeon Maker](http://www.stonesword.com/dungeonmaker.php), which is less fully featured than Dungeon Painter Online but a good backup just in case, [Tiamat](http://www.rpgobjects.com/tiamat/index.php), which falls somewhere in-between, and [PyMapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymapper/), which *is* downloadable, though I had issues with its installer (and I don't have Python on this computer to test the from-source version, though if you had Python you could click-to-run it).

Comment: Maptool is *far* too slow. You have to carefully align each tile. I'm talking like 'click squares to make room' type of software. Maptools is for making pretty maps, not on-the-fly ones.

Comment: Pyromancers looks perfect. If someone hooks me up with a non-web tool I'll probably move to that, but you get the accept until then.

Comment: Found another few: 
http://www.dungeoncrafter3.com/screenshots.php
http://www.dungeonmapping.com/df/public_html/
http://www.yeoldemapmaker.com/

Courtesy of a forum thread: http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?1407-List-of-Mapping-Software

I haven't looked at these myself other than just the examples, but they look potentially promising. The second link is a map-making community with both an older and newer tool, but you do have to register to get them and I'm in a hurry right now.

Comment: Dunjinni is a bit slow as well I think, it is again a tool to make nice pretty maps, not on the fly 'which way is out' maps.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I'm so freeform when I GM that when people ask me for a floorplan I have an anxiety attack. I'm actually going to use some of these in my own campaigns.

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of this more for an old school 'you map it, I don't tell you if the map is right' game, but run online as my local group is more story based. This would let the mapper upload the maps to show other people without having to scan it.

Comment: I just downloaded the tool from the second link above, and I can vouch for how incredibly quick and fast it is. [DungeonForge](http://www.dungeonmapping.com/df/public_html/) does require a registration (on their forum, not like a key or anything), but it's really fast, and it's about equivalent to Pyromancers, though it seems a little shoddy (My advice? Avoid scrolling your mousewheel, that drives it crazy, but otherwise it seems fine).

You can also export it to a .jpg or .png really, really fast and share it.

Comment: Sorry, which second link above? There are lots of them, and many places you could be counting from: Can you clean up your answer to make a clear list, including the one from your comments? Thank you.

Comment: I am having trouble with DungeonForge's export to image; it just copies your viewport, and I don't have a working print-to-image solution on my Win7 Laptop.

The link's the comment about it, I'm technically in a Pathfinder session right now or I'd make everything neat (in other words I'll do it later).

Comment: I had a freind look over them since he is doing something similar to what I want to do, but with old computer RPGs. We both think http://pyromancers.com/dungeon-painter-online/ is exactly what we are looking for: You just click to add rooms, hallways, stairwells, etc. No fuss, etc.

Comment: It seems that the dungeoncrafter3 (win only?) isn't supported much? I click on all but download and I get an error on the webpage. Looking at the other sites, I would guess that not much time is put into the products - probably not a whole lot of money to be made that would allow for more polish.

Comment: Yeah, I can only get the links (to a dead site), the download, and the information things on the homepage to work when I try them. The forum seems "up" in terms of hosting, but the config's off.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Dungeonographer](http://www.dungeonographer.com/)? It's a java app so it runs on at least 2 of your preferred platforms. There's a free version, which will allow you to at least try it out before committing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something as simple as MSPaint? Square boxes of your own sizing with added text wherever you can fit it. Various colors for... whatever. Lava, water, trees, hideous deathtrap of spiked poisonous tentacles. If you're not using this for a battle-map and it's just a way to share an idea of the layout of places, then it doesn't have to be exact.

Keep it simple.

Comment: I'd prefer something that gives a nice grid, as it is then easier to see when you might have missed a hidden room or such, and you have less issues of 'opps I drew that room too big'.

Answer (score 1):

[Hexographer](http://www.hexographer.com) sounds like it may meet your needs (t. There is a free, browser-based version and a $25 desktop version.

It is related to Dungeonographer, which is described in a post that was made after I started writing this one... I would recommend looking at both.

Answer (score 0):

[Gridmapper](https://campaignwiki.org/gridmapper.svg) is a web tool. You can draw the map using your keyboard, which is what makes it fast for me. If you're sitting in different locations, then the mapper can set it to "auto save" and everbody else sets it to "auto load" and it should work, too -- with some lag. Your map will end up saved [on a wiki](https://campaignwiki.org/wiki/Gridmapper/HomePage).